# How can I migrate a WordPress site from MySQL to SQL Server Express?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, migration

I have developed a web portal in WordPress using xampp server. I have my database in MySQL.

Now I need to deploy this WordPress portal on other system with SQL Server Express Edition.

So how can I deploy it successfully with SQL Server?

What software or driver or service will be needed for this deployment on the system?

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621682/import-mysql-database-into-a-ms-sql-server

Comment: Although you are probably able to import the data from the MySQL WordPress database into a SQL Server Express database using the SQL Server Migration Assistant, good luck getting WordPress to issue queries that are compatible with SQL Server.

Comment: @Max so true, I fought with that for over a month, rat's nest of dynamic SQL created all over the PHP landscape, all assuming MySQL syntax. I eventually gave up. I got pretty close with *just* the native WordPress stuff, but the plug-ins were 10x worse.

Comment: funny, I went through that exact scenario and gave up.  Plus side is I now know enough about managing MySQL to actually be dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

You will need SQL Server Migration Assistant to migrate the data. For wordpress to work with MSSQL you also need the "wp-db-abstraction" plugin.
I'm still working on that one...